# Returning the latest record for each category

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I’m trying to parse some data for a dashboard we’re creating. The data I’m looking at has columns: job_num, kit_timestamp, and skid_serial. The skid_serial has the “side” category incorporated (A or B). I'm getting the side using this:

```
RIGHT(LEFT(Skid_Serial, 2), 1)
```

I’m needing just the newest job_num for each side based on the kit_timestamp. Sometimes, production may only run one side, sometimes 2 sides. I need just the single job_num query because it will end up being incorporated into an IN query.

This is what I've tried, but it will return the latest job_num and timestamp for each job that has run on the current day, instead of just the latest.

```
SELECT job_num, max(kit_timestamp) as Kit_Timestamp, RIGHT(LEFT(Skid_Serial, 2), 1) as Side
FROM  Line_Cummins_MDC_Kit_Cell1.dbo.Line_Cummins_MDC_Kit
WHERE CONVERT(date, kit_timestamp) > dateadd(day, - 1, CONVERT(date, getdate()))
GROUP BY RIGHT(LEFT(Skid_Serial, 2), 1), Job_num
ORDER BY kit_timestamp desc
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm not the greatest at SQL, but know this is possible somehow.

Here's an example of the original data:

| Kit_ID | Asm_Num | Job_Num | Part_Num | Skid_Serial | Container_Serial | Operator | Kit_Timestamp | Kit_Weight | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 364821 | I2MK2-0101 | I2MK2-0000 | 5473009 | MB110000 | I2MK2-0000MB122056 | kh | 2022-05-10 09:05:50.923 | 0.0748 | Backflushed |
| 364820 | I2MK5-0523 | I2MK5-0000 | 5473010 | MA110011 | I2MK5-0000MA122077 | th | 2022-05-10 09:05:24.457 | 0.0771 | Backflushed |
| 364819 | I2MK5-0522 | I2MK5-0000 | 5473010 | MA110011 | I2MK5-0000MA122077 | th | 2022-05-10 09:04:41.830 | 0.0772 | Backflushed |
| 364818 | I2MK5-0521 | I2MK5-0000 | 5473010 | MA110011 | I2MK5-0000MA122077 | th | 2022-05-10 09:04:02.953 | 0.0775 | Backflushed |
| 364817 | I2MK2-0100 | I2MK2-0000 | 5473009 | MB110000 | I2MK2-0000MB122055 | kh | 2022-05-10 09:03:27.970 | 0.0746 | Backflushed |
| 364816 | I2MK2-0099 | I2MK2-0000 | 5473009 | MB110000 | I2MK2-0000MB122055 | kh | 2022-05-10 09:02:50.063 | 0.0747 | Backflushed |
| 363762 | I2MH2-0823 | I2MH2-0000 | 5473009 | MB110000 | I2MH2-0000MB122092 | 3 | 2022-05-10 08:42:15.273 | 0.0755 | Backflushed |
| 363761 | I2M5X-0242 | I2M5X-0000 | 5473010 | MA110010 | I2M5X-0000MA122063 | JH | 2022-05-10 08:41:56.210 | 0.0799 | Backflushed |
| 363760 | I2MH2-0822 | I2MH2-0000 | 5473009 | MB110000 | I2MH2-0000MB122092 | 3 | 2022-05-06 12:41:40.490 | 0.075 | Backflushed |
| 363759 | I2M5X-0241 | I2M5X-0000 | 5473010 | MA110010 | I2M5X-0000MA122063 | JH | 2022-05-06 12:40:54.693 | 0.0798 | Backflushed |

The result I'm looking to get is this:

| Job_Num |
| --- |
| I2MK2-0000 |
| I2MK5-0000 |

As you can see, the data has multiple days of data, and an 'A' or 'B' for the second character of the skid_serial, which signifies the side. I'm needing to extract the most recent job_num for each side. Some of these production lines only run a single side at times, so I need to account for that as well.

Comment: Why not just remove the `WHERE`?

Comment: FYI, providing prompt responses/updated to your questions is far more likely to mean your question is answered @Rick . Asking us to wait, or not responding at all, can result in close votes.

Comment: I understand, but my kids come first. Hope you can understand that.

Comment: Understood, it’s my first post on the forum and had no idea it would get immediate attention. Rookie mistake

Comment: Per peeve `WHERE CONVERT(date, kit_timestamp) > dateadd(day, - 1, CONVERT(date, getdate()))` is a pointless complexity (disregarding the performance issues), because if the right side is the beginning of the day then it makes no difference if you cast the left side, So you may as well do `WHERE kit_timestamp > dateadd(day, - 1, CONVERT(date, getdate()))`

Comment: Okay, just added more information and sample data/desired results.

Comment: So, this is optional, but to make it easier to answer you could provide your sample data as DDL+DML or a DBFiddle. That way we don't have to type it all out to assist you.

Comment: I believe I did this right: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8rzYq9m9rpr9XXPZEp7zGD/0

Comment: Your fiddle is for MySQL. Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Try [dbfiddle.uk](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle).

Comment: And you have put in times, in a varchar column, instead of datetimes in a datetime column :) Maybe pick this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=991b9237fdcf107be7f48c0b80051cb5) up and correct it.

Comment: Have a look at the [`row_number` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087388/how-to-select-only-one-full-row-per-group-in-a-group-by-query) and see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So maybe this ROW_NUMBER() based solution will work for you.
However I have doubts about your WHERE condition. Maybe just remove it, unless you don't want to show something from yesterday which happens to be the latest job for a side?

```
SELECT 
job_num 
FROM 
(
 SELECT job_num,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RIGHT(LEFT(Skid_Serial, 2), 1) ORDER BY 
 Kit_Timestamp DESC) as RN,
 Kit_Timestamp 
 FROM  Line_Cummins_MDC_Kit_Cell1.dbo.Line_Cummins_MDC_Kit LK
    WHERE CONVERT(date, kit_timestamp) > dateadd(day, - 1, CONVERT(date, getdate()))
) T
WHERE RN=1
ORDER BY Kit_Timestamp DESC
```

Comment: If you think `row_number` will solve it you should be flagging as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

the following WHERE condition

```
 WHERE CONVERT(date, kit_timestamp) > dateadd(day, - 1, CONVERT(date, getdate()))
```

indicate you want *today* date  in addition to above query you can use

```
cast(kit_timestamp as date) = cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

however to get your desired result the where condtion must be change to

```
 WHERE kit_timestamp > dateadd(day, - 1, CONVERT(date, getdate()))
```

since your data is from yesterday

you can use `Subquery` and `Join` to get you desired result.

```
SELECT job_num
FROM   (SELECT Max(kit_timestamp)             AS Kit_Timestamp,
               RIGHT(LEFT(skid_serial, 2), 1) AS Side
        FROM   sample
        WHERE  kit_timestamp > Dateadd(day, -1, CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()))
        GROUP  BY RIGHT(LEFT(skid_serial, 2), 1)) S1
       JOIN sample S2
         ON S1.kit_timestamp = S2.kit_timestamp
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e953b9b37f303e3f17bee3a3a8f20969)